# How can I invest in ubuntu?

Tags: canonical

Is this even possible for a private person with no major funds?

Answer (score 7):

Ubuntu actually really needs your support. You can now help and support a huge project with small pledges.

You can buy [all sorts of branded gift items](http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=29) and at the download page you can [give freely using paypal](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/questions?distro=desktop&bits=32&release=lts) (the link is an example).

<sub>[credits of the image: http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/7050/115155 ]</sub>

Answer (score 4):

As a matter of fact, you really can invest in Ubuntu. Not the invest in business terms, though. For example, when you download Ubuntu, you are sent to a page where you can select how much money you want to give to Canonical and Ubuntu developers. In return, they you give you more innovative and advanced technologies, like Mir display server and Ubuntu Edge phone.
Other than that, Canonical gives Ubuntu fans chance to invest in their projects with more substantial results. For instance, Ubuntu Edge is that kind of a project. You can invest 730 USD to any sum you want and in return they will give you equivalent amount of Ubuntu Edge phones, ranging from 1 piece to 100 pieces.